# Pandoc lua filter: How to preserve footnotes' formatting?

Tags: html, filter, lua, markdown, pandoc

I try to implement footnotes as defined in [CSS Generated Content for Paged Media Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/#footnotes).
With this definition, footnotes have to be inline `span`s.
I wrote a first draft of a `pandoc` `lua` filter.
It is my first pandoc filter (and also the first time I code in `lua`).

Here's the filter:

```
Note = function (elem)
  local textContent = {}
  local content = elem.content
  for i = 1, #content do
    textContent[2*i-1] = pandoc.Str(pandoc.utils.stringify(content[i]))
    if i < #content
    then
      textContent[2*i] = pandoc.LineBreak()
    end
  end
  return pandoc.Span(textContent, pandoc.Attr("", {"footnote"}, {}))
end
```

It works well for footnotes with unformatted text (formatting is lost due to the use of the `stringify()` function): simple footnotes and multiple  blocks footnotes are well rendered.

In order to preserve formatting, I tried to use the `walk_block()` function on the `content` of the `Note` element, but I cannot obtain any result.

I got a second problem: the `stringify()` function returns a void character string for `CodeBlock` elements.

So, when I use this filter on the following `markdown` text:

```
Here is a footnote reference,[^1] and another.[^longnote]

[^1]: Here is the footnote.

[^longnote]: Here's one with multiple blocks.

    Subsequent paragraphs are indented to show that they
belong to the previous footnote.

        { some.code }

    The whole paragraph can be indented, or just the first
    line.  In this way, multi-paragraph footnotes work like
    multi-paragraph list items.

This paragraph won't be part of the note, because it
isn't indented.
```

I obtain the following HTML fragment:

```
<p>
  Here is a footnote reference,
  <span class="footnote">Here is the footnote.</span>
  and another.
  <span class="footnote">Here’s one with multiple blocks.
    <br />
    Subsequent paragraphs are indented to show that they belong to the previous footnote.
    <br />
    <br />
    The whole paragraph can be indented, or just the first line. In this way, multi-paragraph footnotes work like multi-paragraph list items.
  </span>
</p>
<p>This paragraph won’t be part of the note, because it isn’t indented.</p>
```

The code block is lost. Is there any way to keep both footnotes' formatting and code blocks?

Comment: This will never work as you want. See the HTML spec for the [p tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element). Once an opening tag for any block-level element is found, the `p` element is closed. Therefore you can't put a block level element inside a paragraph. Same goes for `span`, which is a [phrasing content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2) element and can only contain other phrasing content elements. I'm guessing Pandoc's HTML renderer knows this and refuses to output the block level tags where they are not allowed.

Comment: The spec you reference only shows inline level content in the footnote examples. And the [footnote display property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/#propdef-footnote-display) provides a way to indicate whether the content should be displayed as "inline" or "block" content. This is necessary because the footnote itself cannot actually be block content within the `span` tag that holds it. In other words, the spec only provides for a footnote to contain no more than a single paragraph's worth of content, but only the content , not the `p` itself.

Comment: There are things like [Bigfoot.js](http://www.bigfootjs.com/) (site is currently down, see [GitHub project](https://github.com/lemonmade/bigfoot#bigfootjs)), which display footnotes so that they appear inline, but really they use Markdown's common footnote markup (all footnotes at end of document) and use some JavaScript and CSS to make them appear inline. That is very different from the CSS Generated Content for Paged Media Module spec, where they actually are inline.

Comment: @Waylan Thanks for your comments! Following the order of your replies: 1/ what surprised me is the pandoc's definition of the `Note` element https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-types-1.17.5.1/docs/Text-Pandoc-Definition.html#v:Note It is an inline element composed of a list of block elements (it is weird for my brain). But, I agree with you: I can only deal with phrasing content. However, I think it should be possible to keep some simple formatting as bold or emph.

Comment: @Waylan 2/ I agree. That's why I try to use `<br/>` (named `LineBreak` in pandoc). 3/ I prefer to avoid any DOM manipulation with JS (or only very simple scripts). The reason is that I use Prince to produce pdf (the html content is not intended to be used in a browser).

Comment: Linebreaks aren't enough. Code blocks are also block level elements. My point is you can only have whatever fits in a paragraph and nothing more. Of course, that excludes code blocks, lists, blockquotes, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found how to process the `Note` element.

First, the `Note` element is an inline element, so we can use `walk_inline`. The weird thing is that a `Note` element can embed block elements like `Para` or `CodeBlock`.

The following filter deal only with `Para` and `CodeBlock` elements. Formatting is kept.

Since a `Para` element is a list of inline elements, it is obvious to reuse those elements in a `Span` element.
The `CodeBlock` text can also be processed in an inline `Code` element.

```
local List = require 'pandoc.List'

Note = function (elem)
  local inlineElems = List:new{} -- where we store all Inline elements of the footnote
  -- Note is an inline element, so we have to use walk_inline
  pandoc.walk_inline(elem, {
    -- Para is a list of Inline elements, so we can concatenate to inlineElems
    Para = function(el)
      inlineElems:extend(el.content)
      inlineElems:extend(List:new{pandoc.LineBreak()})
    end,
    -- CodeBlock is a block element. We have to store its text content in an inline Code element
    CodeBlock = function(el)
      inlineElems:extend(List:new{pandoc.Code(el.text, el.attr), pandoc.LineBreak()})
    end
  })
  table.remove(inlineElems) -- remove the extra LineBreak
  return pandoc.Span(inlineElems, pandoc.Attr("", {"footnote"}, {}))
end
```

If the `Note` element embeds other types of block elements (like a `BulletList` or a `Table`), one has to develop a specific filter for the `walk_inline` function.

Comment: Pandoc has a function to convert blocks into inlines, but it is not exposed as a Lua function. As I understand, such function would make your life significantly easier. May I suggest to raise an issue for this on the [pandoc issue tracker](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues)?

Comment: @tarleb Thanks for the information! I'm a beginner with pandoc internals. Yes, I think such a function would be a great helper.

Comment: You could even try to implement it yourself. You'd want to expose `blockToInlines` from module Text.Pandoc.Shared by adding it to the list of functions Text.Pandoc.Lua.Module.Utils. The most difficult thing would be to setup a Haskell development environment.

Comment: Thanks for your support! I'm a little bit scared by Haskell. I see this language only for first-class developers (I'm only an amateur developer). `lua` seems more accessible. I will first open an issue an have a look to these internals.

Comment: I can relate. I tried (and failed) to use Haskell three times before I finally got something productive out of it. It's not that it is difficult, it is just very different. Now it's fun though ;)

Comment: Thanks @tarleb! I love pandoc and now, lua filters. Thanks for your great work!